# php create global object, load class <- in function

Tags: php

```
<?php

class hello {

    public function echo() {
        return 'omg';
    }

}

function world() {
    global $a;
    $a = new hello();
}

world();
$a->echo();
```

How i can implement this idea? it is possible?

Comment: Aside from the fact that you can't use echo as a method/function name, you're returning a value from your method, but not doing anything with it in your main code

Comment: The next question is why you'd want to cobble together such a hotch-potch of approaches in this way, especially with the abuse of global

Comment: Why would you want to do such thing? Why not just create local instance of `hello` on the call site, and do what you want with it? What's the point of `$a` being global?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting..In my view please dont try to use echo as a function name..

```
class hello{
            public function display()
            {   return 'omg';
            }
}
function world()
{
    global $a;
    $a = new hello();
}
 world();
echo $a->display();
```